# Why the map in the command does not change the type of map that is binded to the property that is changing?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a map and I want to bind the map type to the property, but I have a problem. When I click on the button, the property and the map type must change. I thought that is problem in Binding,but if I change property in constructor it changet and in a command does not work. The command also works, because when you click, the picture on the button changes.
I tried to go through the code through f10 and I see that the property gets the value of the map type, but the map itself does not change this type

```
    <customclasses:CustomMap
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1, 1"
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
        MapType="{Binding MyMapType}">
    </customclasses:CustomMap>


    public MapPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = new MasterPageVM();
    }


    partial class MasterPageVM : BaseViewModel
    {
        #region Fields
        MapType myMapType { get; set; }
        #endregion

        #region Properties
        public MapType MyMapType
        {
            get => myMapType;
            set
            {
                if (this.myMapType == value)
                    return;

                this.myMapType = value;
                this.NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Constructor
        public MasterPageVM()
        {
            MyMapType = MapType.Hybrid;

            StandartMapCommand = new Command(StandardSelected);
            SatelliteMapCommand = new Command(SatelliteSelected);
            HybridMapCommand = new Command(HybridSelected);

        }
        #endregion

        #region Command
        public Command StandartMapCommand { get; set; }
        public Command SatelliteMapCommand { get; set; }
        public Command HybridMapCommand { get; set; }
        #endregion

        #region Methods
        public void StandardSelected()
        {
            MyMapType = MapType.Street;
        }

        public void HybridSelected()
        {
            MyMapType = MapType.Hybrid;
        }

        public void SatelliteSelected()
        {
            MyMapType = MapType.Satellite;
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

I took the extra code, but the main problem here is that the map in the command does not show the changed map type, but the changed one has changed to a new one

Comment: does it work if you use a standard Map control instead of CustomMap?

Comment: No.it also does not work. and I do not understand why

Comment: can you help me?

Comment: Have you looked closely at application Output in Visual Studio? Maybe set a breakpoint on `this.NotifyPropertyChanged();` then look at Output. Maybe `MapType` isn't two-way binding by default.  Try changing `MapType="{Binding MyMapType}"` to `MapType="{Binding MyMapType, Mode=TwoWay}"

Comment: Thank you.I`ll try